# Open window which user select language

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a short form for selecting language for a webpage, There are two languages one is **marathi** and another is **english** actually what I want is like: when a user select english language and submit the form `english.html` page should open and
when user select marathi language `marathi.html` page should open.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select Language</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="hen.png">

<form>
<center>
    <p id="p1">
    Language:<select>
            <option id="English" >English</option>
            <option id="Marathi" >Marathi</option>
            </select>
    </p>
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Open" >
</center>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to redirect to a page based on the user's choice?

Comment: Yes user choice language

Answer (score 1):

You can use this as a reference, considering english.html and marathi.html as your targeting pages, you can change them accordingly

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Select Language</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="hen.png">
    <script>
        $('#button').click(function() {
            var selected = $('#language option:selected');
            window.location.href = selected + ".html"
        })
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <form>
        <center>
            <p id="p1">
                Language:
                <select id="language">
                    <option id="English">English</option>
                    <option id="Marathi">Marathi</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="Open">
        </center>
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its obviously, but please do not repeat it at production:

```
 <input type="submit" id="button" onclick="window.locaton.href='lol/'+$('select').val()+'.html'" value="Open" >
```

Comment: Why not repeat it at production?

Comment: because it's tottaly unclear and 0-maintained. as better alternative:  @Praveen Rana answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43470354/4074041. But in real world, you need use some MVVM pattern (not necessarily a framework), for detach logic and ui.

Comment: Fair enough.  I disagree for something so basic, but it's a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is easy way;

`<select name="forma" onchange="location = this.value;">
 <option value="english.html">English</option>
 <option value="marathi.html">Marathi</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create this using simple Javascript then use `location.href = "yourPageAddress";`

here is the sample code i have written for the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function MyFunction(){
            var getValue = document.getElementById("language");
            //console.log(getValue);
            var getIndexValue = getValue.options[getValue.selectedIndex].value;
            //console.log(getValue.selectedIndex);
            //console.log(getIndexValue);

            if(getValue.selectedIndex == 1){
                //console.log("English")
                location.href = "http://www.google.com";
            }
            else if(getValue.selectedIndex == 2){
                //console.log("Marathi");
                location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
            }
            else{
                console.log("Wrong Option Selected.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Language:
<select name="language" id="language">
    <option>Select..</option>
    <option value="https://www.google.com" id="english">English</option>
    <option value="https://www.yahoo.com" id="marathi">Marathi</option>
</select>
<br>
<button name="submit" id="submit" onclick="MyFunction()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is just the one way where you can redirect the user to selected page, there are many different ways also to execute the same operation.
You may find some console.log statement marked comment, which was just used for debugging purpose.